# NoSQL solution with fast Map/Reduce

Tags: nosql

There are 3 high load sites (>400k unique visitors per day), they all are tightly connected, have same admin interface, sharing user accounts etc... Sites have following statistics items: visitors, unique visitors, user path, referer, time on site, on page, region, country and browser. Statistics is aggregated and processed by 3rd party service, but this service can't provide cross-site statistics in a convinient manner (lots of manual checks and tracking of users) so I want to build a statistics solution which will provide functionality described above and also provide cross-site statistics. And now I'm in doubt: what should I use for storage? First I've tried to use good old MySQL and that totally failed: performance and scalability issues were killing whole idea. So I've started to look at NoSQL solutions, but I don't have much experience with them and I'm seeking for advice which solution should I use that will fit following requirements:

- Non-blocking map/reduce. Map/Reduce shouldn't block collection for writing (so when admin requests some statistics data sites would be still able to add visitor records)
- Easily scalable.
- Users are counted on the beginning of request lifecycle, so response from database should be really fast

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While grabbing a few freebies from a conference in the Spring, I spent a few min's sitting through a presentation that covered several mongoDB use cases, one that appears applicable is the case of [ServerDensity](https://blog.serverdensity.com/choosing-a-non-relational-database-why-we-migrated-from-mysql-to-mongodb/). Their blog entry describes a similar high volume logging system, along with the reasoning behind their decision to move from mySQL to MongoDB, and in particular why mongoDB rather than the competition. There are other presentations along similar lines kicking around e.g. [Eventbrite](http://blog.eventbrite.com/guest-post-why-you-should-track-page-views-with-mongodb/), [Yotta](http://www.slideshare.net/jrosoff/realtime-analytics-with-mongodb-mongodb-meetup-nyc), [Devmash](http://devsmash.com/blog/mongodb-ad-hoc-analytics-aggregation-framework)

There's also a chapter (5 - Web Analytics using MongoDB), of PHP and MongoDB Web Development Beginner's Guide, By Rubayeet Islam, that covers building such a system.